# Store multiple items in a dictionary to print later

Tags: excel, vba, dictionary, web-scraping

I've written a script in vba to scrape different categories out of coffee shops from a webpage. The categories I'm trying to parse are `shopname`,`address` and `phone`. I've already defined the selectors within my script. The problem I'm facing is I can't store them in a dictionary to print them later.

If it were for two items, I could have handled them like the way I've already shown. I get confused when there is another item, as in phone (currently it is commented out below) come into play.

> ***How can I store three items in a dictionary and print them?***

```
Sub GetDictItems()
    Dim key As Variant, Html As New HTMLDocument, URL$, R&
    Dim post As HTMLDivElement, shopName$, address$, phone$
    Dim idic As Object: Set idic = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    URL = "https://www.yellowpages.com/search?search_terms=Coffee%20Shops&geo_location_terms=San%20Francisco%2C%20CA&page=2"

    With New XMLHTTP60
        .Open "GET", URL, False
        .setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0"
        .send
        Html.body.innerHTML = .responseText
    End With

    For Each post In Html.getElementsByClassName("info")
        shopName = post.querySelector(".business-name span").innerText
        address = post.querySelector(".adr").innerText
'       phone = post.querySelector(".phones").innerText
        idic(shopName) = address
    Next post

    For Each key In idic.keys
        R = R + 1: Cells(R, 1) = key
        Cells(R, 2) = idic(key)
    Next key
End Sub
```

Reference to add to execute the above script:

```
Microsoft XML, v6.0
Microsoft HTML Object Library
```

> `My intention here to learn as to how I can store multiple items in a dictionary in order to print them later.`

Expected output:

[image]

Comment: `idic(shopName) = Array(address, phone)` etc

Comment: `Cells(R, 2) = idic(key)(0) : Cells(R, 3) = idic(key)(1)`

Comment: Sorry @Tim for any misunderstanding. What if there are 5 items, then? I've updated the post. You perhaps understand now what I tried to mean. Thanks.

Comment: The point of a dictionary is that you enter a word in English (say) and get its translation to French (say). Your need would be more like a phone book: enter the name and get the address and phone number. That is all good, except that you mention printing the list. You don't mention lookups.  For printing a simple, 2D array would suffice, like Dim Arr(1 to 5, 1 to 3). Arr(1,1) = "Outerlands", Arr(1,2) = "4001 Judah St", Arr(1,3) = 4156616140. Each element of the array has 3 parts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I like the answer already given (+). You can also load arrays into the items.

```
For Each post In Html.getElementsByClassName("info")
    shopName = post.querySelector(".business-name span").innerText
    address = post.querySelector(".adr").innerText
    phone = post.querySelector(".phones").innerText
    idic(post) = Array(shopName, address, phone)
Next post

For Each key In idic.keys
    R = R + 1: ActiveSheet.Cells(R, 1) = idic(key)(0)
    ActiveSheet.Cells(R, 2) = idic(key)(1)
    ActiveSheet.Cells(R, 3) = idic(key)(2)
Next key
```

You could also work with only arrays which should be quick.

```
Dim list As Object, arr(), post As Object, index As Long
Set list = Html.getElementsByClassName("info")
ReDim arr(1 To list.Length)

For Each post In list
    index = index + 1
    shopName = post.querySelector(".business-name span").innerText
    address = post.querySelector(".adr").innerText
    phone = post.querySelector(".phones").innerText
    arr(index) = Array(shopName, address, phone)
Next
For index = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
    ActiveSheet.Cells(index, 1).Resize(1, UBound(arr(index))) = arr(index)
Next
```

I would however seek to load `html.getElementsByClassName("info")`  into a variable and work with that in both cases.

---

As an aside the data is present in a json string within a script tag so if using a json parser, e.g. [jsonconverter.bas](https://github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-JSON/blob/master/JsonConverter.bas) you can also do:

```
Dim json As Object, item As Object, results(), i As Long
Set json = JsonConverter.ParseJson(Html.querySelectorAll("script[type='application/ld+json']").item(1).innerHTML)
ReDim results(1 To json.Count)
i = 1
For Each item In json
    results(i) = Array(item("name"), Join$(item("address").Items, " ,"), item("telephone"))
    i = i + 1
Next
```

Comment: Cos HTMLDivElement won't support querySelector.

Comment: Updated both versions. Annoying some element types do support (test case I used does). I may have  a further look now have an URL.

Comment: This is the very logic `idic(post) = Array(shopName, address, phone)` that did the trick. It is genuinely awesome. Although Tim Williams suggested in his comment in the first place but that was not clear enough to go with real demo. Thanks QHarr for making my day.

Comment: Sorry for my interruption @QHarr. ***Something is seriously wrong if I comply with this logic `idic(post) = Array(shopName, address, phone)` beacuse [this script](https://pastebin.com/0nyKm1Hs) produces duplicates whereas dictionary never stores duplicate values.*** Do you think it's a valid approach (what actually a dictinary does). Thanks.

Comment: Dictionaries can store duplicate values but not duplicate keys. Are you saying you having duplicate keys? If so add in a counter variable and use that for the key. You are, I think using an object as keys. They maybe the same object type but are not technically the same object.

Comment: Keys, I meant actually.

Comment: I’ll have a look at your script now.

Comment: You are using overwrite syntax btw.

Comment: Try the following: https://pastebin.com/NL4kqeqJ . Note you actually should scroll to bottom of page if you want all listings.

Comment: You didn't get my point @QHarr. I used those selectors intentionally even if I knew that it would produce duplicates. All I wanna say is that whatever selectors I use or how many duplicates are there, It should not print any duplicate results as long as I'm storing them into a dictionary. Check out [this implementation](https://pastebin.com/dUMMVJ2Z). Even when I've used the same selectors, It will produce unique results only. Hope you got it. Thanks for being with me.

Comment: I think I do understand. You should use the right selector to give you the unique values.  Your version is relying on the fact that a,b,c are always the same for the additional elements you are looping over so with overwrite syntax you are simply updating the same key with the same values multiple times. This doesn't occur when you use object as key as this is distinct and so you have additional keys though values are again the same. It is an xy problem. You are fixing the result of not using the right selector.  However, if you want to do it this way use idic(a & b & c) = Array(a, b, c)

Comment: And hope you don't go over the length of the key allowed. This is why this solution is risky and is also inefficient IMO.

Answer (score 3):

Another possibility would be to create simple class for the data. And then add instances of this class to the dictionary. Two additional classes `WebData` and `InfoDataCollection` will help to separate the code and improve readability etc.

> GetDictItems method

```
Const url = "https://www.yellowpages.com/search?search_terms=Coffee%20Shops&geo_location_terms=San%20Francisco%2C%20CA&page=2"

Sub GetDictItems()
    With New WebData
        .Load url
        .PrintToExcel
    End With
End Sub
```

> WebData class module

```
Private m_html As HTMLDocument
Private m_data As InfoDataCollection

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    Set m_html = New HTMLDocument
    Set m_data = New InfoDataCollection
End Sub

Public Sub Load(url As String)
    With New XMLHTTP60
        .Open "GET", url, False
        .setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0"
        .send
        m_html.body.innerHTML = .responseText
    End With
    m_data.Add m_html
End Sub

Public Sub PrintToExcel()
    Dim key As Variant
    Dim R As Long
    Dim info As InfoData

    For Each key In m_data.Keys
        R = R + 1
        Set info = m_data.Items(key)
        Cells(R, 1) = info.ShopName
        Cells(R, 2) = info.Address
        Cells(R, 3) = info.Phone
    Next key
End Sub
```

> InfoData class module

```
Private m_shopName As String
Private m_address As String
Private m_phone As String

Public Property Get ShopName() As String
    ShopName = m_shopName
End Property

Public Property Let ShopName(ByVal vNewValue As String)
    m_shopName = vNewValue
End Property

Public Property Get Address() As String
    Address = m_address
End Property

Public Property Let Address(ByVal vNewValue As String)
    m_address = vNewValue
End Property

Public Property Get Phone() As String
    Phone = m_phone
End Property

Public Property Let Phone(ByVal vNewValue As String)
    m_phone = vNewValue
End Property
```

> InfoDataCollection class module

```
Private m_dictionary As Object

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    Set m_dictionary = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
End Sub

Public Sub Add(html As HTMLDocument)
    Dim info As InfoData
    Dim post As HTMLDivElement

    m_dictionary.RemoveAll
    For Each post In html.getElementsByClassName("info")
        Set info = New InfoData
        info.ShopName = post.querySelector(".business-name span").innerText
        info.Address = post.querySelector(".adr").innerText
        info.Phone = post.querySelector(".phones").innerText
        Set m_dictionary(info.ShopName) = info
    Next post
End Sub

Public Property Get Keys() As Variant()
    Keys = m_dictionary.Keys
End Property

Public Property Get Items() As Object
    Set Items = m_dictionary
End Property
```

Comment: It's a long time since I came across your solution @dee. Nice implementation as always.

Comment: Although the question has accepted answer already I would like to add some more code which will introduce the next possibilities how to separate the code into classes.

Comment: Honestly speaking I need a user manual to run your script @dee. I've always been a novice in vba. Would appreciate any guideline about the use case. Thanks a lot.

Comment: No problem, have a look e.g. [here](https://excelmacromastery.com/vba-class-modules/). It is just separation of concerns so each class takes care of part of the problem.

Answer (score 2):

It seems I can achieve the result like below. I'll kick out my answer if any better approach comes along:

```
For Each post In Html.getElementsByClassName("info")
    shopName = post.querySelector(".business-name span").innerText
    address = post.querySelector(".adr").innerText
    phone = post.querySelector(".phones").innerText
    idic(shopName & "|" & address & "|" & phone) = 1
Next post

For Each key In idic.keys
    R = R + 1: Cells(R, 1) = Split(key, "|")(0)
    Cells(R, 2) = Split(key, "|")(1)
    Cells(R, 3) = Split(key, "|")(2)
Next key
```